# Bulk Insert a List of Custom Class Data into SQL through ADO.Net in C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have bulk inserted a dataset into SQL. But i am not sure, how to insert a collection of data (A List) into a SQL table. I also need to maintain transaction for the whole insert process.

I tried as shown below.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            using (SqlTransaction sqlTran = sqlConn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (CustomClass item in ListOfData)
                    {
                        string query = "Build the Query Here";
                        SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn, sqlTran);
                        sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    sqlTran.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    sqlTran.Rollback();
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
       }
```

But i am not sure, if it is a correct way to proceed..?
Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is bulk, I would still use SqlBulkCopy. As long as the data isn't **immense**, I would construct a DataTable from the list (perhaps using reflection or FastMember), then just pass that to a SqlBulkCopy instance (and supply the transaction).

Comment: I would roughly have a max of 500 rows of data. Should i proceed in my way or should i convert my data back to data table.

Comment: @Muthukumar that's borderline - I'd certainly consider SqlBulkCopy for that. Note my mention of DataTable here is merely as a tool for this one specific purpose; everywhere else I'd keep it as a list of a class. Don't go changing everything to DataTable - think of the kittens!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable info Marc.